# Почему условие WHERE IN не работает вместе с WHERE LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Делаю простой поиск по пользователям. Необходимо выбрать из таблицы всех пользователей, у кого имеется один id из списка `[70, 53, 21, 41]`, и добавить несколько других условий для выборки (`WHERE LIKE`). Получается следующий SQL-запрос:

```
select * from `users`
where `id` in (70, 53, 21, 41)
and `first_name` like '%asd%'
or `last_name` like '%asd%'
or `email` like '%asd%'
or `phone` like '%asd%'
```

При выполнении запроса выдаются пользователи, которые отсортированы по условию `WHERE LIKE`, но без сортировки по `id`. При этом, если строить такой запрос:

```
select * from 
(select * from `users` where `id` in (70, 53, 21, 41)) as `filtered` 
where `first_name` like '%asd%' 
or `last_name` like '%asd%' 
or `email` like '%asd%' 
or `phone` like '%asd%'
```

то всё работает прекрасно. Интересно, почему в первом варианте не выполняется запрос `WHERE IN`?

Comment: Потому что скобки забыли? `where \`id\` in (70, 53, 21, 41)
and (\`first_name\` like '%asd%'
or \`last_name\` like '%asd%'
or \`email\` like '%asd%'
or \`phone\` like '%asd%')`

Comment: Точно, со скобками работает, совсем про них забыл. Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для соблюдения условия выбора по лайку в представленном множестве не хватает выделить эти доп. условия в скобки, чтобы они читались как отдельное атомарное условие. В ином случае происходит поиск по условиям `OR` без учёта условия поиска по `IN`.

```
select * from `users`
where `id` in (70, 53, 21, 41)
and (`first_name` like '%asd%'
    or `last_name` like '%asd%'
    or `email` like '%asd%'
    or `phone` like '%asd%'
)
```